# Bootstrap Navigation in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

PHP code:

```php
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

     <?php
    $args=array( 'theme_location'=>'main_menu',
                 ' menu'=>'mainmenu',
                ' menu_class'=>'navbar-nav'
                );
    
    wp_nav_menu($args);
    ?>
</div>
```

The function:

```
register_nav_menus(array('primary' =>'top menu header' ,'main_menu'=>'mainmenu'));
```

What is the wrong in arguments for navbar bootstrap in Wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not output a bootstrap-friendly HTML navigation structure. You will need to use a navwalker function to set up navigation to support bootstrap navbar. You can use [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker), or create your own navwalker if you wish.